# KeyCloak LDAP Role mapper with AD groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, keycloak, federation

I have a KeyCloak LDAP federation question.

Using LDAP Federation I am trying to map specific AD groups to one specific KeyCloak role.

**Example**

*Fido* belongs to the AD Group "Dogs"

```
(LDAP:memberOf:cn=dogs,cn=users,dc=test,dc=com)
```

*Fluffy* belongs to the AD Group "Cats"

```
(LDAP:memberOf:cn=cats,cn=users,dc=test,dc=com)
```

I can get LDAP Federation to create the "cats" and "dogs" roles but what I really want to do in keycloak is have a role called "animals" that both fluffy and fido are assigned to.

Is this possible using the role-ldap-mapper?
Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible using the role-ldap-mapper? Is there another way to
> do this?

First you need to map those groups "cats" and "dogs" from LDAP into roles in Keycloak, for that you can use the `role-ldap-mapper` Mapper. During the creation of those Mappers, after saving click on `"Sync LDAP Roles to Keycloak"`.

[image]

After you have successfully import those roles into keycloak for each of the imported roles (i.e., `cat` and `dog`):

- Go to Roles;
- Click on the role in question;
- Switch "Composite Roles" to `ON`
- Select the role Animals (I am assuming that you have already created that role in Keycloak, otherwise do so);
- Click on "Add selected"

[image]

Next time a user with the role `Cats` or `Dogs` from LDAP authenticates with Keycloak, the role `Animals` will show up in the token as well.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to achieve the same thing but with `Groups` instead of `Roles`? If it is somehow possible, could you please explain shortly how?